# Кирилица в PythonInterpreter

Tags: python, java, кодировка

Собственно проблема: не нашел возможности сменить кодировку в Jython (из джавы, не в консольке самого джитона), по умолчанию стоит ascii, и с кирилицей работать, само собой, не получается. Может, есть способы?
Если пробовать передавать кирилицу, хотя бы сделав что-то вроде interpreter.exec("print пфва"); , 
на выходе получаются знаки вопроса ????

Jython 2.5.3, пробовал 2.2 - то же самое.

Answer (score 1):

`jython` понимает стандартную декларацию для кодировки исходного кода:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jython
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u"Do You Want To Build A \N{Snowman}?" # ☃ - работает
print u"\u043c\u0438\u0440" # тоже работает, даже если coding: ascii
print u"мир" # требует coding: utf-8
```

Если декларацию не использовать, то всё равно первые две строки в примере продолжат работать, т.е. она нужна только чтобы использовать не ascii символы в самом исходном коде.

Если хочется писать русские буквы прямо в java коде, то при компиляции можно указать, какая кодировка использовалась, если система использует что-то другое по умолчанию:

```
$ javac -encoding UTF-8 JythonSourceEncodingTester.java
```

java тоже использует `\uxxxx`, поэтому необходимо использовать двойные слэши:

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
import org.python.core.*;

public class JythonSourceEncodingTester {
    public static void main(String []args) throws PyException
    {
    PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter() {
             {
                 cflags = new CompilerFlags(CompilerFlags.PyCF_SOURCE_IS_UTF8);
             }
         };
    System.out.println("Hello, brave new мир");
    // \u043c распознаётся джавой
    interp.set("unicode_string", "\u043c\u0438\u0440");
    interp.exec("print unicode_string, type(unicode_string)");
    interp.set("same", "мир"); // абсолютно тоже самое
    interp.exec("print same, type(same)");
    interp.exec("assert same == unicode_string");
    interp.exec("print u'\\N{Snowman}'"); // \\N{..} распознаётся jython
    interp.exec("print u'\\u043c\\u0438\\u0440'"); // \\u... распознаётся jython
    // печатает ???, если PyCF_SOURCE_IS_UTF8 не используется
    interp.exec("print u'мир'");
    System.out.println("Goodbye, cruel мир");
    }
}
```

`PyCF_SOURCE_IS_UTF8` нужен только для `print u'мир'` строчки, всё остальное работает, как есть.

Comment: Я попробовал ваше решение, вышло так:
создал папку, в ней файл JythonSourceEncodingTester.java с описанным вами кодом и файлик jython.jar. Cледующей командой скомпилировал это дело
javac -classpath .;.\jython.jar -encoding UTF-8 JythonSourceEncodingTester.java
Запустил там же в командной строке, как результ:
Hello, brave new ьщЁ
Exception in thread "main"...LookUp error: no codec search function registered: can't find encoding 'cp866'
вот как-то так...а хорошо было бы в нетбинсе как-нибудь настроить чтобы все работало, без использования командной строки

Comment: @kraft_lawrence: В Jython 2.5.3 cp866 кодировка присутствует даже на Linux. Сама кодировка понадобилась чтобы напечатать Юникодную строчку в консоли, что требует преобразовать её в байты, потому что jython, по-видимому, не использует Юникодное Win32 API, такое как WriteConsoleW(). Крякозябы в консоли могут быть от того, что редактор исходный код не в utf-8 сохранил (если известна кодировка, которую редактор использует, то её нужно javac указать вместо utf-8). Как указать кодировку исходного кода в NetBeans, я не знаю, но ответ такой же, как для java.

Comment: в нетбинсе пока не получилось ничего хорошего добиться, а то, что я пробовал в консольке, так там исходный файл в кодировке utf-8 был...смена кодировки консоли на utf-8 привела лишь к тому, что стала выбрасываться ошибка LookUp error: no codec search function registered: can't find encoding '65001'

Comment: @kraft_lawrence: Осталось три вопроса: 1. [как сменить кодировку исходного кода в нетбинсе](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans) -- открой свойства проекта, рядом с Sources выбери encoding и поменяй. 2. Выяснить, почему кодеки не установлены в jython -- (пере)установи Jython 2.5, кодеки в стандартной установке присутствуют. 3. Почему крякозябы в консоли -- можно начать с `System.out.println("Hello, brave new \u043c\u0438\u0440");` -- если это работает, то дальше двигаться.